# How to reduce the size of rich text area field in visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce

I am trying to reduce the size of rich text area field in Visualforce page.
Here is the code have written-

```
<apex:column headerValue="Extra Curricular Activities"  >
    <apex:inputField value="{!c.Extra_Curricular_Activities__c}" style="width:50px" />
</apex:column>
```

Where i need to make the changes,can anybody help me with this?
Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: What have you tried? Did you search for any solution?

Comment: Yes, have used div class, but still the same, nothing has changed.

Comment: I have tried with div class for input field, but still nothing has changed.